# NextJs - External synchronous scripts are forbidden

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using nextJs version 11.x

When trying to include an external script like below, getting an error when executing the yarn build.

```
<Head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.externalsite.com/style.css" />
<script src="https://www.websote.com/viewer.min.js"></script>
</Head>
```

Error :

```
./pages/_app.js
63:17  Error: External synchronous scripts are forbidden. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-sync-scripts.  @next/next/no-sync-scripts
```

I am using eslint.

So, how can we include this external js ?

Comment: try using Script component https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script

Comment: Thanks for replying... i tried the same but no luck :(

Comment: Issue solved by keeping the eslint validation to "extends": "next"

Answer (score 17):

Resolved the problem.

It was happening because of eslint strict configuration. Now I changed this to Base.

Modified content in this file .eslintrc

Earlier the value was

```
   {
   "extends": "next/core-web-vitals"
   }
```

Now changed the content to

```
 {
 "extends": "next"
 }
```

Thanks for the Help

Comment: Yes' It work for me , i have modify the file .eslintrc.json with the same . it working thanks.

Comment: Worked for me in 2022!

Comment: To clarify, this works because the `next` ESLint configuration is less restrictive than the `next/core-web-vitals` one, and does not enable the rule `@next/next/no-sync-scripts` which is what triggered the error.

Answer (score 12):

```
import Script from 'next/script'

const Home = () => {
    return (
      <div class="container">
        <Script src="https://third-party-script.js"></Script>
        <div>Home Page</div>
      </div>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Here's more details about it: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-sync-scripts

Comment: this is the wrong answer, because this is client side.

Answer (score 4):

Modify ESLint configuration file, disable the `no-sync-scripts` rule mentioned by the error message works.

```json
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "rules": {
    "@next/next/no-sync-scripts": "off"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `<script></script>` inside `_document.js`  use `async` or `defer` keyword

```
        <script
            defer
            src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
            crossOrigin="anonymous"
       ></script>

          <script
            async
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
            crossOrigin="anonymous"
          ></script>
```

If in your component, use this

```
import Script from 'next/script'
```

Comment: Nice tips: Worked with <script defer src="xxxxxx" for me to load Google Places script in _document.ts in Nextjs. Thanks!

PS. <Script> from next/script didnt worked for Google Places...

Answer (score 1):

For nextjs,
Instead of using   use   imported from next/script.

An example is given below :

```
import Script from 'next/script';
```

Use async or defer

```
<Script src="https://third-party-script.js" async />
<Script src="https://third-party-script.js" defer />
```